# How to make a search bar on JavaScript with for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML and JS:

```
<body>

    <div class = "to_do_list">

            <div class = "add"></div>
            <div id = "delete"></div>
                
            <input id = "input" type = "text" name = "">

            <div id = "add_button"></div>

            <div class = "find"></div>
            <input id = "find_form" type = "text" placeholder = "Find">
            <button id = "find_button" type = "submit">Start</button>

            <div class = "thing_container"> </div>

    </div>
    
</body>
```

```
    let storage = [];

    addButton.onclick = () => {


       let newElement = document.createElement("li");

       newElement.style.background = 'purple';
       newElement.textContent = input.value;
       thingContainer.appendChild(newElement);

       storage.push(newElement);


   }

      findButton.onclick = () => {

        for (let i = 0; i < storage.length; i++) {

           if (storage[i].textContent.indexOf(find_form.value) >= 0) {
              storage[i].style.display = "block";
           }

           else {
              storage[i].style.display = "none";
          }
   }
```

By clicking on the `addButton` the code creates a `li` element, appends to it the text that was inside an `input` and appends the `li` element to the `thingContainer` and then to array, named `storage`

So, when in the last fragment of code (onclick on findButton) I put into square braces a certain index (for example 1) - it works, but when I do by such way as here - it does not. Could you help hot to fix it?

Will be thankfull for any answer.
ghr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below snippet.

```js
let storage = [];
let addButton = document.getElementById('add_button');
let findButton = document.getElementById('find_button');
let thingContainer = document.getElementById('thing_container');

addButton.onclick = () => {
  let newElement = document.createElement("li");
  newElement.style.background = "purple";
  newElement.textContent = input.value;
  thingContainer.appendChild(newElement);
  storage.push(newElement);
};

findButton.onclick = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < storage.length; i++) {
    if (storage[i].textContent.indexOf(find_form.value) >= 0) {
      storage[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      storage[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<body>

    <div class = "to_do_list">

            <div class = "add"></div>
            <div id = "delete"></div>
                
            <input id = "input" type = "text" name = "">

            <button id = "add_button">Add</button>

            <div class = "find"></div>
            <input id = "find_form" type = "text" placeholder = "Find">
            <button id = "find_button" type = "submit">Start</button>

            <div id= "thing_container"></div>

    </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, it's helped.